# Como descobrir por qual pasta o usuário realizou upload?

Tags: php, upload

Gostaria de saber como descobrir por qual pasta o usuário fez o upload no formulário?

Por exemplo, se o usuário fez o upload pela pasta **X**, se o arquivo estava dentro da pasta X, eu gostaria executar o seguinte código:

```
$upload = copy($arqTemp, $pasta . $nomePDF);
$pastaExcluir = "C:/Users/Administrador/Desktop/X/";    
unlink($pastaExcluir . $arqName);
```

Ou se ele fez um *upload*, de fora da pasta específica eu simplesmente uso o `move_uploaded_file()`:

```
$upload = move_uploaded_file($arqTemp, $pasta . $pdfName);
```

Então, **como** eu vou descobrir por qual pasta foi enviado o arquivo?

Comment: Não sei se entendi bem sua pergunta. Mas quando um usuário faz upload de um arquivo, os seus dados vem na variavel $_FILES. Os arquivos são imediatamente movidos para a pasta temporária do servidor (normalmente /tmp em linux).

Comment: Por uma questão de privacidade (e é bom que seja assim) os navegadores não enviam os caminhos reais dos arquivos de origem. Se sua aplicação depende disso, é o caso de repensar no problema e criar outra solução.

Comment: @Bacco, repensei bem (muito tempo(mentira, foram minutos)) e abandonei essa ideia kkkkk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entendi que você quer excluir o arquivo depois que o usuário fez upload. Certo?

Assumindo que sim, você *não conseguirá* fazer isso. Quando o usuário faz *upload*, você recebe a cópia desse arquivo e faz o que quiser com ele, mas não tem acesso ao sistema de arquivos do cliente nem tem como saber que este arquivo veio de lá.

Se a aplicação estiver rodando no computador do próprio cliente, você tem acesso ao sistema de arquivos, mas permanece sem ter como saber de onde o arquivo veio. O browser não fornece esta informação.

Se isso for realmente muito importante, talvez você consiga utilizando algum plugin, criando alguma extensão para o navegador ou algo assim, o que foge do escopo do PHP.