# Como acessar a versão de um arquivo .exe com JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, arquivo

Gostaria que me ajudassem a resolver um pequeno problema.

Preciso acessar a propriedade chamada "versão" no meu arquivo, e sei que isso é feito em Javascript. Mas não sei qual tag usar, ou o que fazer para chegar a isso. Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Um arquivo tipo .txt, .doc, imagem/*? Arquivos desse tipo?

Comment: Não.. um arquivo .exe

Comment: Através de Javascript não é possível. Tudo que você consegue acessar é o tamanho, tipo, data da última modificação e o nome, veja https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#dfn-file

Comment: você poderia indicar algo possível para verificar  a versão dele?

Comment: a claro.. mas de preferência uma que faça ligação com WebDesing

Comment: Existem perguntas no [so], por exemplo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16524899/getting-file-creation-date-and-author-in-javascript-or-html?rq=1, que mostram que não é possível.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Através de JavaScript somente, não existe uma maneira de acessar a **versão de um arquivo `.exe`**.

Se você está usando [`File()`](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#file), de acordo com a própria [W3C](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#dfn-file), os únicos valores retornados de um determinado arquivo são:

- A sequência de bytes;
- O tamanho do arquivo;
- O nome do arquivo;
- O tipo de arquivo;
- A data de última modificação;

---

Como dito nos comentários também, reforçando a resposta:

> [...] Nem mesmo o *path* fica exposto [...]

Pelo comentário já subintende-se que você não consegue descobrir nem o caminho real que foi realizado o *upload*. Essa questão da privacidade do usuário, é levada realmente muito a sério pela W3C.

Pode ler mais sobre nessa outra pergunta relacionada: [Como descobrir por qual pasta o usuário realizou upload?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/187157/66203)

Comment: Só para deixar claro, nem mesmo o path fica exposto. Ele fica escondido debaixo de um fakepath

Comment: Sim @JeffersonQuesado, eu fiz uma pergunta assim a muito tempo https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/187157/66203, e recebi uma resposta explicando. No próprio [pt.so] mostra C:/fakepath na hora do upload.

Comment: ótimo pergunta, por sinal

Comment: Bem antiga @JeffersonQuesado, uma das minhas primeiras xD.

Comment: Alguém acha possível fazer a mesma coisa porém em outra linguagem.. tipo php?

Comment: @Alis com PHP acredito que seja possível. Dê uma olhada no [`stat()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.stat.php)

Comment: Poderia ceder mais algumas dicas?